# Get a value of slide dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I have [this demo](http://emprego.xtreemhost.com/slider/).

The value only updates if I refresh the page, but my idea is to update the value when the pointer is moved.

I use [this plugin](http://blog.egorkhmelev.com/2009/11/jquery-slider-safari-style/) but I think that is based on the jQuery UI slider.

In my code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#SliderSingle").slider({
    from: 400,
    to: 2000,
    step: 2.5,
    round: 1,
    scale: ['400â‚¬', '600â‚¬', '800â‚¬', '1000â‚¬', '1200â‚¬', '1400â‚¬', 
                                            '1600â‚¬', '1800â‚¬', '2000â‚¬'],
    dimension: '&nbsp;â‚¬',
    skin: "round",
    slide: function(event, ui){
      $("#amount").val('$' + ui.value);
    }

  });
  $("#amount").val('$' + $("#SliderSingle").slider("value"));

});
</script>
```

The only issue is just update the value when pointer is moved.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#events check out the change event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is built on the jQueryUI slider. However, you should be able to use the `callback` option, which accepts a `value` parameter:

```
$("#SliderSingle").slider({
    /* Snip */
    callback: function(value) {
        $("#amount").val("$" + value);
    }
    /* Snip */
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HKhBH/